# Как сделать умный поиск в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, поиск

```
text = 'Word 1' 
list = {'Word1':'found','Word2':'not found'}
```

Мне нужно найти text в list при этом могут быть ошибки, допустим Ward1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью модуля `re`, если вы можете предугадать, какие именно могут быть допущены ошибки (самые частые - `о` вместо `a`, `и` вместо `e` и т.д.).
Подробнее о регулярных выражениях в python можно почитать на Хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/

Второй вариант решения задачи (когда заранее неизвестно, какие ошибки может допустить пользователь) - использование нечёткого поиска. Однако могу предупредить, что нечёткий поиск не так эффективен для коротких запросов. Он больше предназначен для длинных фраз.
Например, он хорошо сработает, если нужно найти фразу `Мама мыла раму дважды`, но уже не так хорошо сработает, если нужно найти `Рама`.
Чем больше символов в строке, тем лучше работает алгоритм нечёткого поиска.
Реализации алгоритма можно найти на Вики [https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Реализации_алгоритмов/Расстояние_Левенштейна](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), если нужно подробнее разобраться в алгоритме - о нём тоже можно почитать на Хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/279585/

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос относится к задаче парсинга текста.
С Python знаком не очень глубоко, но скорее всего эта задача где-то уже решена.
Если нет, то она решена, например, для XML и тогда просто стоит вопрос о встраивании готового кода в программу на Python.

P.S.  Под windows есть редактор кода notepad++,  который можно использовать для решения подобных задач.  Там механизм парсинга встроен в поисковую систему.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение проблемы. Можно воспользоватся методом Левенштейна.

```
def distance(a, b):
    "Calculates the Levenshtein distance between a and b."
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        # Make sure n <= m, to use O(min(n, m)) space
        a, b = b, a
        n, m = m, n

    current_row = range(n + 1)  # Keep current and previous row, not entire matrix
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
            if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                change += 1
            current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

    return current_row[n]
alph = {'brave':'tekst pro brave','unicue':'tekst unic'}
text = str(input())
u = ['brave','unicue']
for a in range(0, len(u)):
    try:
        if int(len(u[a])/2) >= distance(u[a],text):
            print(alph[u[a]])
    except:
        pass
```

**UPD:**

```
def distance(a, b):
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        a, b = b, a
        n, m = m, n

    current_row = range(n + 1)
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
            if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                change += 1
            current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)
    return current_row[n]

def transliterate(text):
    text = text.lower()
    for c in punctuation + whitespace:
        text = text.replace(c, '')
    for c, r in alph.items():
        text = text.replace(c, r)
    return text

def search(text, dict):
    text = transliterate(text)
    lt = {}
    for name in dict:
        lt[name] = {}
        if len(name) == len(text):
            lt[name][name] = distance(text, name)
        elif len(name) > len(text):
            for i in range(0, len(name)):
                q = name[i:len(text) + i]
                if len(text) > len(q):
                    break
                lt[name][q] = distance(text, q)
        elif len(name) < len(text):
            for i in range(0, len(text)):
                q = text[i:len(name) + i]
                if len(name) > len(q):
                    break
                lt[name][q] = distance(text, q)
    res = {}
    lst = lt
    for name in lt:
        items = list(lst[name].items())
        items.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
        o = 99999
        for i in items:
            if i[1] <= o:
                lst[name][i[0]] = i[1]
                o = i[1]
    lt = lst
    del lst
    for name in lt:
        c = 99999
        res[name] = {}
        for val in lt[name]:
            if c >= lt[name][val]:
                res[name][val] = lt[name][val]
                c = lt[name][val]
        res[name] = {}
        for val in lt[name]:
            if c >= lt[name][val]:
                res[name][val] = lt[name][val]
                c = lt[name][val]
    result = {}
    for name in res:
        for val in res[name]:
            result[name] = res[name][val]
            break
    del res
    r = result
    c = 99999
    for name in list(result):
        if result[name] > c:
            del r[name]
        elif result[name] < c:
            c = result[name]
    for name in list(result):
        if result[name] > c:
            del r[name]
        elif result[name] < c:
            c = result[name]
    result = []
    for name in list(r):
        result.append(name)
    return result
```

Это делит текст на части и рассматривает их, выдает список с результатами